# Do these colored streaks mean that my CF card is bad?

Tags: troubleshooting, sensor, shutter, data-corruption, cfcard

I have been shooting with the same Nikon d700 for about three years (about 200k clicks). I started seeing a streak run across one out of every 250 images (example here: http://wp.me/aRb6L-1lT). So, I bought a used D700 (about 3k clicks) and am having the same problems.

Is this a coincidence and I have two bad sensors or shutters, or do I have a bad card?

Comment: Wow. You must be well heeled if you see a problem like that and replace the camera before the memory card!

Comment: CF cards are relatively cheap -- the very first thing you should do is to try to reproduce the problem using other cards.

Comment: _Have_ you tried another card? How are you getting the data _off_ of the card?

Comment: In particular, relative to @mattdm's question: Do you see the problem with images on the LCD of your camera? Or only on the computer? You may have a faulty connection, transfer, cable, reader, etc.

Comment: Also do you regularly reformat the card?

Comment: do the streaks look the same on each affected image, or different?  Can you show 2 or 3 different examples ... from each camera?  Normally JPEG corruption makes funny blocks.  Or are you saving raw files?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities

- File corrupts on your CF card, try another one
- File corrupts while transferring to your computer, try using a different memory card reader, avoid using cheap chinese reader / cables and USB hubs. And also do not use the front panel USB sockets of your desktop computer, these, in general, use very cheap and unshielded cables.
- File corrupts while processing on your computer, your computer might have defective memory chips (RAM) you can test your computer's memory with memtest86

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem with the shutter or the sensor. If you look at the image you see that there is a horisontal shift where the error starts, that can not be the result of a problem with the shutter or sensor.

The data got corrupted somewhere after it was read from the sensor, so the most likely candidate is that it happened when saving to the memory card.

Answer (score 0):

1st get your machine to factory settings and update firmware if possible but dont you dare do that with the broken cf you mention. If you are in wedding photography you should have more than 1 cf so after this reset please take some photos on the other card. If your problem is not solved your processor should be damaged cause I have seen many sensor and shutter problems but nothing like this. This can be cause while processor converting the image, writing down the image or the cf storing the image. "detailed version of guffa's answer" lol :D